# Cell formatting error when exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have a Class to export a generated report to Excel, and I have a cell which contains duration formatted as `hh:mm:ss` or `d.hh:mm:ss` (i.e.: `67:43:34` or `2.19:43:34`) but when I export it to Excel it formats the cell as a date so I get `1900-01-02 19:43:34`. Is there anyway during the exportation I can specify excel to use the right formatting for those cells?

[Here's the code](http://pastie.org/private/j3jrmqi0c4amy638gtmara)

*(will post screenshot or piece of code if needed)*

Comment: How are you exporting? You know you can prefix any data in cell with a single quote `'` and it will not be evaluated? You can format cells as text `Cells.NumberFormat = "@"` to prevent from converting..

Comment: @mehow added link to Pastie for the code